# JsonPath - Filter Array and get only the first element

Tags: arrays, json, jsonpath, json-path-expression

Im trying to filter the elements of this JSON array to return only the first element it will find.

```
{
    "elements": [{
        "urn": "urn:li:lyndaCourse:189800",
        "details": {
            "classifications": [{
                    "associatedClassification": {
                        "urn": "urn:li:lyndaCategory:9331",
                        "type": "LIBRARY"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "associatedClassification": {
                        "urn": "urn:li:lyndaCategory:8982",
                        "type": "SUBJECT"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "associatedClassification": {
                        "urn": "urn:li:lyndaCategory:8920",
                        "type": "LIBRARY"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }]
}
```

But this results in an EMPTY array `[]`.

I tried this JSONPATH query in https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/

`$.elements[0].details.classifications..associatedClassification[?(@.type=='LIBRARY')][0]`

Expecting to get:

```
[{
    "urn": "urn:li:lyndaCategory:9331",
    "type": "LIBRARY"
}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to filter the information is by filtering the property "classification" (without using ".."), and use "associatedClassification.type" in your filter, so you should have something like this:

```
$.elements[0].details.classifications[?(@.associatedClassification.type=='LIBRARY')]
```

With the above JSONPATH you will have all items which type is "LIBRARY" (in your example will return 2 items).

You mentioned you need only the first one of the filtered items, as far as I investigated it seems there's no posible solution to return only the first item using only JSONPATH (see the thread bellow):

https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath/issues/272

Comment: In my testing, the .. works, and its also documented here https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#:~:text=books%20and%20bicycles-,%24.store..price,-The%20price%20of anyway - my main problem is getting the first item of the result set and yeah it looks like it can't be done just by jsonpath.

Comment: You're totally right, I didn't know it, I will modify the answer, thank you

Answer (score 1):

The following works on all elements:

```
$..classifications[?(@.associatedClassification.type=='LIBRARY')]
```

and returns a list of all matching associatedClassification objects.

JSONPath is expected to point inside the original document. Therefore, getting the first element from the result list would require post-processing, e.g. a separate JSONPath, e.g.

```
$.[0]
```

Comment: Thank you! It took me a lot to find this solution.